# Three separate tables that sit left to right next to each other centered

Tags: html, html-table, center

I am attempting to have a series of tables sit next to each other from left to right while being centered.

```
<div>
<table border="1px"; style="float:left";>
    <!--left side Advertisement-->
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p><img src="http://www.radiorebel.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/RadioRebelJamMaestroAd.png"></p>
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>

<!--Player Table Collective-->
<table border="1px"; width="500"; height="500"; style="float:left";">
    <td>
        <!--Wavestreaming.com online Status-->
        <p>Status: <span data-shoutcast-value="status"></span></p>
        <!--Wavestreaming Song Title-->
        <p>Now Playing: <span data-shoutcast-value="songtitle"></span></p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <!--Album Art and PlayerTable-->
        <p>Album Art goes here</p>
        <p>Player goes here</p>
    <!--Third Table in the Player Collective-->
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>Stuff</p>
            </br>
        <p>stuff 2</p>
            </br>
        <p>stuff 3</p>
    </td>
</table>

<!--right side advert-->
<table border="1px"; style="float:left">
    <td>
        <p><img src="http://www.radiorebel.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/RadioRebelJamMaestroAd.png"></p>
    </td>
</table>
```

By using `float:left` in my tables I have been able to get them to sit next to each other, but I have not been able to center the tables. I tried wrapping everything in a div and telling to to center everything, but that does not seem to work.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the first div to:

```
<div style='position: absolute; width: 80%; left:50%; margin-left: -40%;'>
```

As long as the margin-left is - half the width, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left`.
Then use the div style `text-align=center` on the enclosing div.
Will also need to add `vertical-align=top` to each table style.
See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/KJhhc/

Comment: Stan, Please see if you can upvote the answers that worked for you. We value the votes a lot within the stackoverflow community. Also please "mark as answer" the solution that you chose.

Answer (score 0):

Concept is to set the width for `<div>` and specify margin-left and margin-right to auto.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<body>
<div style="width:1020px; margin:0 auto;">
<table border="1" style="float:left">
    <!--left side Advertisement-->
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p><img src="http://www.radiorebel.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/RadioRebelJamMaestroAd.png"></p>
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>

<!--Player Table Collective-->
<table border="1" width="500" height="500" style="float:left">
    <td>
        <!--Wavestreaming.com online Status-->
        <p>Status: <span data-shoutcast-value="status"></span></p>
        <!--Wavestreaming Song Title-->
        <p>Now Playing: <span data-shoutcast-value="songtitle"></span></p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <!--Album Art and PlayerTable-->
        <p>Album Art goes here</p>
        <p>Player goes here</p>
    <!--Third Table in the Player Collective-->
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>Stuff</p>
            </br>
        <p>stuff 2</p>
            </br>
        <p>stuff 3</p>
    </td>
</table>

<!--right side advert-->
<table border="1" style="float:left">
    <td>
        <p><img src="http://www.radiorebel.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/RadioRebelJamMaestroAd.png"></p>
    </td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked for me thank you! This was my first time reaching out to the internet for help with code and I am not disappointed. Thanks again!